# Why are my entities only partially populated when loading them using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, datanucleus

I'm using Spring Data JPA and DataNucleus as JPA persistence provider and have something like

```
interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
    Book findByAuthorId(Long id);
}
```

If I call `bookRepository.findByAuthorId()` and then access `book.publishingHouse.manager.name` is `null`. As opposed to calling `bookRepository.findAll()` when the fields are populated correctly all the way. I set `datanucleus.DetachAllOnCommit=true` and `datanucleus.maxFetchDepth=-1` (I also tried with 10).

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any additional transaction boundaries defined, the `EntityManager` closed when leaving the query method. That means what you get back is detached entities and what kind of load state you get back is determined by the defaults the persistence provider uses.

You basically have two options:

- Have a client (service or controller class) using `@Transactional` to keep the `EntityManager` open and thus the loaded instances eligible to lazy-loading to pull data out of the store while you use the instance. If a controller or service is not enough, you might wanna look into the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`/`-Interceptor` which basically keeps the `EntityManager` open until the view is rendered.
- Define what should be fetched explicitly either using JPA 2.1 entity graphs (see the [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph) for details) or explicitly adding fetch-joins to the query by defining it manually.

Comment: It worked with the interceptor. What puzzled me was that using `findAll()` was working.

Comment: We're passing an empty criteria query to the `EntityManager` for `findAll()`. Seems like DataNucleus treats those differently. Glad to hear you got it working though!